# Who is maintaining tensorflow on conda?

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, conda

I understand Tensorflow is only officially released via pip. I am just wondering who is maintaining https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/tensorflow-gpu and https://anaconda.org/anaconda/tensorflow-gpu ? Are they affiliated with your group, or just some anonymous third party? Thank you!

Comment: Sounds related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69584461/570918

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that they are not maintained by the TensorFlow team directly.  That said, they are not just "anonymous third party" either.  The conda-forge community (https://conda-forge.org/) and Anaconda Team (https://www.anaconda.com/) are respectable established groups within the Python community.  That said, if you want the officially maintained version, you should stick with `pip`.

Comment: So they are still trustworthy in general, like, it's unlikely some one will find some trojan horse there, right?

Comment: Yes: I would be comfortable using them in my projects, and would be extremely surprised if there are trojans there.